# Populating imported row with formulas in columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I have this dataflow:

1. Multiple Google Forms responses feeding Google Sheets tabs' rows
2. Those Google Sheets tabs' rows feeding into one "Summary" tab, mapped properly

On this "Summary" tab, I have some helpful scripts running, including:

- One that populates certain columns in each row with formulas (so that those newly imported mapped rows have fully blank rows to feed into)

**Currently, that's working well as an onEdit function**

- If I edit one row's column V, for example, it'll show up in column AE, as you see below, which is great.

However, I keep running into trouble trying to get this to AUTOMATICALLY run when a new row is auto-imported into that "Summary" tab.

I tried to use the same script with a "change" trigger, and that didn't do the job.

```
function PrepopulateCellsOnEdit(e) {
    var range = e.range;
  if (!range) return; // Check if range is null and exit early if it is

  var column = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  // Check if the edited sheet is "Summary"
  if (sheetName !== "Summary" || row === 1) return;


// Apply formula in column AE to reference column V for the edited row
if (column == 22 && row > 1) { // Column V = 22
  var formulaAE = "=V" + row;
  sheet.getRange(row, 31).setFormula(formulaAE); // Column AE = Column 31
}

  // Apply formula in column CD to reference column F for the edited row
  if (column == 6) {
    var formulaCD = "=F" + row;
    sheet.getRange(row, 82).setFormula(formulaCD);
  }

  // Evaluate the formula in column E and concatenate values from columns V and AX for the edited row
  var valueV = sheet.getRange(row, 22).getValue();
  var valueAX = sheet.getRange(row, 50).getValue();
  if (valueV && valueAX) {
    var formattedValueV = Utilities.formatDate(valueV, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "M/d/yyyy");
    var formattedValueAX = Utilities.formatDate(valueAX, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "M/d/yyyy");
    var concatenatedValue = formattedValueV + " - " + formattedValueAX;
    sheet.getRange(row, 5).setValue(concatenatedValue);
  } else {
    sheet.getRange(row, 5).setValue("");
  }

    // Apply today's date in column U for every row with data
  var today = new Date();
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(today, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "M/d/yyyy");
  for (var row = 2; row <= lastRow; row++) {
    sheet.getRange(row, 21).setValue(formattedDate);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form responses do not trigger the `onEdit` function. Try modifying your code to use the `onFormSubmit` trigger.

If that is not the right direction, I would suggest you create a minimum reproducible demo sheet and script that you can share publicly here.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful reply! Instead of trying to get those formulas to populate from edit or change upon rows being moved programmatically, I added the code for those formulas to my script that's actually moving those rows, and that worked.